# Select between dates issues

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have this SQL:

```
$sql="SELECT * 
FROM   table 
WHERE  expiresdate >= Date(Now()) 
       AND expiresdate <= Date_add(Date(Now()), INTERVAL 10 day) 
ORDER  BY expiresdate ASC";
```

it should basically show all rows in the database that are going to expire within 10 days time however, lets say the expiredate was 2013-03-06 - this row will not display on any day after the expiredate

does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This might help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989385/mysql-datetime-comparison

Comment: what type is `expiresdate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be what you need:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    `table`
WHERE
    expiresdate <= CURDATE() + INTERVAL 10 DAY
ORDER BY
    expiresdate ASC
```

Comment: Can somebody explain, why the query in question won't work. I understand how the above query works.

Comment: Is your table name actually `table`? If so, you need to escape it as it's a reserved word.

Comment: no the table name is not table - i was just using this as an example. i will test this code and let you know how i get on - thanks for the responses

Comment: By the way, is `expiresdate` a `DATE` field?

Comment: yeah it is a DATE field - should it not be? i am still getting the same problem :(

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't actually explained it clearly.

Comment: Well - say the expiredate is 2013-03-06 (yesterday) it will display the row from the database 10 days before the expire date but when its actually on the day it doesnt display

Comment: I've tested it and it works. If I do the above query it will show those with an expiry date between 2013-03-08 and 2013-03-17 which is expected. What results are you getting?

Comment: ok so im my database, i have one row with the expiresdate is 2013-03-06 and it is not displaying.

this is very odd :/

Comment: That's because it was yesterday. You asked for those that expire between today and 10 days from now.

Comment: aha sorry - this is my initial question/statement

it should basically show all rows in the database that are going to expire within 10 days time however, lets say the expiredate was 2013-03-06 - this row will not display on any day after the expiredate

Comment: so basically, i need it to show where the expires date is today + 10 days or if it is in the past

Comment: No problem; if you click the tick next to my post you'll mark it as accepted so that others can see that it answered your question.