# How to do less than, more than with wpdb (wordpress database)?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

How do I do the less than AND greater than `$date` in wpdb?

```
$date = ('Y-m-d');

$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_history WHERE enddate = "%d";', array($date)));
```

I wan't to get history where enddate is today or in present time, BUT also more than `0000-00-00`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql datetime comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989385/mysql-datetime-comparison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

`$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_history WHERE enddate  >= CURDATE()'));`

It will work definitely.

Incase of Date with Time, you have to select field DATETIME in MySQL and in that case you should run query something like

`$wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT * FROM product_history WHERE enddate  >= NOW()'));`

Using this query, You can filter data from current time.